# You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. in token interceptor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to make an interceptor to refresh the token, but it throws me this error and I don't know why

`ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.`

token-interceptor.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { catchError, map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(
        private auth: AuthService,
        private http: HttpClient
    ) { }


    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            catchError((err: any) => {

                if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {

                    if (err.url.includes('signin') || err.url.includes('refreshToken')) {
                        return next.handle(req)
                    }

                    //if error is not about authorization 

                    if (err.status !== 401) {
                        return next.handle(req)
                    }


                    this.renewToken(req).subscribe(request => {
                        return next.handle(request)
                    })



                } else {
                    return throwError(err)
                }

            })
        )
    }

    renewToken(req: HttpRequest<any>) {
        return this.http.get(`${environment.API_URL}/refreshToken`, { withCredentials: true }).pipe(
            map((res: any) => {
                //update access token
                this.auth.setToken(res.token)

                return req.clone({
                    setHeaders: {
                        authorization: `Bearer ${res.token}`
                    }
                })
            })
        )
    }
}
```

***Ignore this: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details. It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this piece of code is wrong:

```
this.renewToken(req).subscribe(request => {
  return next.handle(request)
})
```

istead it should be:

```
return this.renewToken(req).pipe(switchMap(request => next.handle(request)));
```

you are just returning nothing in your variant, that is why it doesn't work.

also the whole logic of token interpceptor seems weird to me. I believe you should rethink about how you want it to work. for now as I see you sending request without token and in almost all cases you are sending it again unmodified, and the one that I fixed above will send it again with token. Wouldn't it be right to add token every time, and only send it 2nd time if token is outdated?

Comment: Thank you! I don't understand in the end what you meant. The request to update the token will only be sent if there is an error trying to access. If this error is 401 it means that you have problems with authorization so the token that has already expired or never started the session.

Comment: basically every time you call `next.handle(req)` you are making a http request. I believe that is not what you wanted to achieve

Comment: Should I replace next.handle (req) with return?

Comment: I believe you should have token in memory. and, if it is no longer valid, then you refresh it. next.handle(addToken(req)).pipe(catchError(is403ThenRefreshTokenAndRetry))